# How to execute console command from the controller

Tags: symfony, console

I am using symfony 2.3

I have command in `ACME\TopBundle\Command\CrawlerCommand.php`

I use this command from console.

```
$ app/console top:crawler
```

But now I want to execute command from the Controller.

```php
public function indexAction(){

    // I want to execute command 
}
```

How can I make it?

I am trying the solution that @Amine suggested.

I have two quesions.

1) How can I check the console output?

I have checked the [console output class](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/ConsoleOutput.html) method.

but

```
$output->getStream()
```

it doesnt show the console log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way is to declare your command as service

```
MyCommandService:
class: MyBundle\Command\MyCommand
calls:
    - [setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]
```

and in your controller call it like this

```
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
    .
    .
    public function myAction() {
      $command = $this->get('MyCommandService');

      $input = new ArgvInput(array('arg1'=> 'value'));
      $output = new ConsoleOutput();
      $command->run($input, $output);
   }
```

or you can use this exemple: https://gist.github.com/predakanga/3487705

i prefer first solution.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to do this ..but I have two quesions ,could you see when you have time ? thanks...

Comment: Thank you I close this question for now,how to handle stream is another quesion.I will make another thread. thank you very much @anime!