# How to use the console log when calling command from controller

Tags: symfony

According this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597956/how-to-execute-console-command-from-the-controller)

I made the code to call command from the controller

```
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
    .
    .
    public function myAction() {
      $command = $this->get('MyCommandService');

      $input = new ArgvInput(array('arg1'=> 'value'));
      $output = new ConsoleOutput();
      $command->run($input, $output);
   }
```

I can get the $output then,

I want to use the console output in Controller

So, I have checked the [console output class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597956/how-to-execute-console-command-from-the-controller) method.

I guess getStream() is something useful,so I try this

```
$output->getStream()
```

But it just return the stream,,

How can I use the console log in Controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with custom streams, you can create your own:
php.net/stream_wrapper_register

`ConsoleOutput` extends `StreamOutput` extends `Output` implements `OutputInterface`.

The `Command` requires the latter as the output argument.

The `StreamOutput` requires a stream as its first argument, you are add your own stream here.  Run the command and read from your stream.

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/StreamOutput.html

A simpler solution may be to extend the `Output` class and implement the `doWrite` method to send data back to the controller, but the first solution sound like more fun.